# Declare view elements in another class (context not clear)

Tags: java, android, view, android-context

I am creating a dynamic UI programatically and in main class I am creating UI element so that I can later add it to `TableLayout` view. Normally I declare it like this:

```
TextView tw_1_2 = new TextView(this);
```

where `this` is the context. Since I never get to understand context clearly can someone tell me how can I declare this `TextView` in another class (as public static for example) and what should I put in context if I want to declare this view in some other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to send context from your activity that you call new class. for this purpose you can use constructor to send context data to the new object of class. I have an example that show how to create a constrctor and use it.
for example this is your ExampleClass:

```
public class ExampleClass{
    private final Context context;

    public ExampleClass(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
    }

}
```

and in your Activity Class do this:

```
ExampleClass ex1 = new ExampleClass(MainActivity.this);
```

and if you want use your class as static you must only define your class and context variable as static without constructor and set context equals your context.
I hope this help you.

Comment: Keeping the context as a weak reference would cover the cases when the calling activity ceases to exist (and so does its context).