# How to Android getContext in a class within another class?

Tags: java, android, class

In my android app, I'm building a login screen using the standard android login template. In this code template there is a class within the activity called UserLoginTask. If a user logs in successfully I want to set the user as a sharedPreference, and for this I need the context. So I use this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
```

Unfortunately I get an error saying:

> The method getContext() is undefined for the type
>   LoginActivity.UserLoginTask

Does anybody know how I can get the context from within the UserLoginTask?

Comment: maybe this is duplicate question that I have answered before. see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190281/declare-view-elements-in-another-class-context-not-clear/19190559#19190559

Comment: Use `LoginActivity.this` in place of getContext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LoginActivity.this` instead of `getContext()` to access the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `UserLoginTask` extends `AsincTask`. In this case pass the shared preferences in the task:

```
private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    SharedPreferences sp;

    UserLoginTask(SharedPreferences sp){
        this.sp = sp;  
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do whatever you need with the sp property
        return null;
    }

}
```

and the call is something like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
new UserLoginTask(prefs).execute();
```